# IE shows my image only 1 pixel high

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Please check out this example, first in FF, Chrome or Safari:

[demo link removed]

You will notice a large image. It will actually scale as you resize your window. It is a fluid image inside a fluid container. Now check it in IE8 or IE7. It is only 1 pixel high :(

I was suspecting that IE requires some sort of width fix to give it some base dimension, so I was playing around with giving the image a min-height of 75%, or a min-width of 75% in case it concerns a portrait image. That indeed gives it the height that is needed, however, it breaks the resize feature. With a min-height of 75%, resize the window to a narrow width to see what I mean, it will lose the aspect ration of the image.

Why oh why can't IE respect these liquid widths and heights?

**PS:** I was thinking about hasLayout fixes, but that is removed from IE8 and doesn't seem to work in earlier versions for this specific case either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply removing the entire `height` attribute on the image fixes it in IE, Firefox, Chrome.

Comment: You're right in that it does show the image in IE then, but the unwanted side effect is that the image no longer scales when you resize the window :(

Comment: Removing the `height` attribute in each of IE, Firefox, Chrome with the respective Firebug-like tool in each browser, the image still scales exactly the same when I resize the window as it did before I removed the attribute (with the exception that the 1px image problem in IE8 is fixed). Am I going loopy here?

Comment: Ok, glancing again at your current live code, you have this: `<img src="http://ferdy.dnsalias.com/apps/jungledragon/images/143/1355_large.jpg" width:75% />`. It should not be `width:75%`, but `width="75%"`.

Comment: @thirtydot: My bad, I had your suggestion implemented but mistakenly put width:75% instead of width="75%" in the HTML, must be because of this CSS allnighter. Thanks!

Comment: @thirtydot: Now there's a coincedence. I just fixed this and posted above only to find out you pointed out the same mistake. PS: I'm going to remove the demo link now.

Comment: An amusing coincidence indeed :)